# Which sets do these half-built pieces belong to? Lime green vehicle, long yellowish vehicle, creature with claws

Tags: set-identification

Which set does each one of these belong to?

[image: lime green vehicle]

[image: long yellowish vehicle]

[image: creature with claws]

Answer (score 10):

The first looks like 60181 [Forest Tractor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60181-1) [image: Forest Tractor]

The second looks like 60178 [Speed Record Car](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60178-1) [image: Speed Record Car]

The third looks like 31073 [Mythical Creatures](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=31073-1) [image: Mythical Creatures]

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate your response.

Comment: 2nd one does have 3 distinctive pieces from that set, but it's clearly a custom design, as most of the other pieces are not from that set.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I agree - but it's mostly that one. I'm glad I didn't go down the rabbit hole of looking for **those** pieces!